Version control of text files with entirely different content across versions
Some calculations in my project result in short (ASCII) output files, but quite some time (multiple hours).
Therefore, I would like to have these output files under version control.
However, the numeric content of these files is inevitably entirely different across versions and it doesn't really make sense to work with diffs on these files.
Is there a best practice to work with the files in commonly used version control systems like git?
I could imagine using a certain tag on these files to avoid diffs on them.

What do you mean with "avoiding diffs"? The fact that VCSs use deltas or not to store information (which, by the way, git does not use... It stores entire snapshots of commits every single time) should not be something you should care about as a user.

You can use .gitattributes to define specific diff procedure or even mark them as "binary" (which the docs explicitly mention as an option when "... the content, while technically composed of text characters, is opaque to a human reader").

I don’t understand what the problem with diffs are. Is it that using git diff is not informative? What is “work with diffs”? If you are worried about space inefficiency then that might be premature. Sure Git is optimized for working with text files which vary little between versions so that it can use deltas in pack files. But text files tend to be small so it often isn’t a problem compared to megabyte-sized binary files.

I think you need to provide more details or rewrite the question. The first two sentences don't really make sense (at least not to me). What I read is: 1. My project outputs small text files. 2.) These text files take a long time to generate. And then: therefore, I want them in source control. I'm not sure why either 1 or 2 leads to wanting them under source control? What do you plan to do with the output files?
